# why as IEnumerable is not enumerated by string.Join

Tags: c#

given the following running method:

```
internal static void DefaultShow(object o) {
    if ( o is IEnumerable) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1024);
        foreach(var i in o as IEnumerable ) {
            sb.Append($"{i}|");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
    }
}

DefaultShow("a,b,c".Split(","));
```

displays:

> "a|b|c|"

when:

```
internal static void DefaultShow(object o) {
    if ( o is IEnumerable) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", o as IEnumerable));
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
    }
}

DefaultShow("a,b,c".Split(","));
```

displays:

> System.String[]

Comment: Be careful with `string` (since it's `IEnumerable<char>`).

Comment: @John well seen (if sayable in english)

Comment: "well spotted" :) Unfortunately it has bitten me before so I'm aware of it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [list of overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) of `string.Join`, none of them accept an `IEnumerable`. There's one that accepts an `IEnumerable<string>`, but that's it.

Therefore, your call to `string.Join` will bind to the overload that takes a `params object[]`. From the perspective of the method, the `object[]` has only one element, and that is the `IEnumerable`, so it calls `ToString()` on that and returns.

You probably want to cast the `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<object>` first, then convert everything to a string by `ToString`:

```
internal static void DefaultShow(object o) {
    if ( o is IEnumerable) {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", (o as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().Select(x => x.ToString())));
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check which method is used

[image]

The (o as IEnumerable) is treated as an item of object array(because of params), while the method you need expectes IEnumerable<string>.

Update: Btw, I don't know why the Visual Studio shows me that the first argument has char type - it should be string, seems to be an issue with VS))

Answer (score 0):

Because `string.Join("|", o as IEnumerable)` will use this overload:

```
public static string Join(string separator, params object[] values)
```

There is no overload which takes `IEnumerable` as a parameter. There is overload only for generic version (`IEnumerable<T>`).

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine(o) will call o.ToString() internally and that will display System.String[] because variable o is a string array.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are joining as `IEnumerable`. So to show the all items you should cast to `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
if (o is IEnumerable<string>)
{             
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", (o as IEnumerable<string>)));             
}
else
{
     Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why do you check: `o is IEnumerable`. It is not used anywhere.